# "input line is too long" when entering string in Java console

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, system.in

When I input a string of 4500 characters followed by a newline feed in Java console, it displays `input line is too long` runtime error in the terminal.

I have tried using both `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`, but no success.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `String` in a file first and read it from there?

Comment: do u mean FileInputStream

Comment: Is there any line breaks in the String input? Or is it a continuous String of text?

Answer (score 1):

My advice when working with big strings is to use StringBuilder Class, here is an example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String someString;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        someString = builder.toString();
        System.out.println(someString);

    }
}
```

Comment: What if input contains continuous spaces or tabulators? `next()` will ignore them.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question firstly, if you want not to ignore them you should change scanner.next() with scanner.nextLine()

Comment: StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            //sumit = ab.nextLine();
            for (int jc=0;jc<l;jc++)
             builder.append(ab.read());
             in1 = builder.toString();

Comment: i dont have any spaces in between